# Get Google authorization from java program open browser for asking already given permission

Tags: java, google-app-engine, batch-file, authorization

In order for a java program to access my google drive I need to create an oauth2.Credential using a json credential file (see https://console.developers.google.com) for getting an access token.

[image: Credentials with client id]

The problem is when I create the Credential java instance the java program open Internet Explorer and ask permission for Drive.

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow
                 , new LocalServerReceiver())
                 .authorize("user")
                 ;
```

[image: Program automatically opens browser and ask permission]

If I click button "allow" , Credential is created and I get a token.

```
 System.out.println("token" + credential.getAccessToken());
```

[image: Browser after clicked on Allow]

[image: Java console view in Eclipse : token get]

The problem is that this java program will be a batch program so we can't ask the batch to click on a button.

Furthermore in https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 my Drive has already given access to my application (application name is GoogleTest) ...

[image: application already granted]

Do you know how to get the credential without java program open browser for asking permission ?
Thank you

Here the full code :

```
 public static void getToken ()  {
     HttpTransport httpTransport ;
     InputStream inputStream;       
     try {
         httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
         List<String> scope = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
         inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/dev/ws/mainAzure/GoogleTest/res/client_secret_jcb_inst.json");
         InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
         clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,reader);                             
         GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport
             , JSON_FACTORY
             ,clientSecrets
             , scope)
             .setAccessType("offline")
             .setApprovalPrompt("force")
             .build();                  

         //Browser open when there is new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(...)
         Credential credential =    new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow
             , new LocalServerReceiver())
             .authorize("user")
             ;
     System.out.println("token" + credential.getAccessToken());
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help (thank you Harold) I could find the solution:
One need to define a datastorefactory, elsewhere the refreshToken is not stored in a file and Google via Internet browser ask for permission each time.
So I added :

```
dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("C:/dev/ws/mainAzure/GoogleTest/res"));
```

and :

```
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport
             , JSON_FACTORY
             ,clientSecrets
             , scope)
             .setAccessType("offline")
             .setApprovalPrompt("force")
             .build();
```

become :

```
            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport
                 , JSON_FACTORY
                 ,clientSecrets
                 , scope)                     
                 .setAccessType("offline")
                 .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                 .setApprovalPrompt("force")                 
                 .build();
```

Furthermore to have an access non limited to 1 hour, one need to refresh the token :

```
credential.refreshToken() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's authorization code flow for you. You can re-use the same credential, provided you are accessing the same Google account.

Consider getting the access code manually with refresh tokens, and manually inputing it into the batch code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the goal is to have a programm accessing data from google Drive without manual intervention injecting an access token.I am looking a solution for that. Do you think it's not possible to get a token automatically ?

Comment: look into Installed Application flow for Google Api. i think that's what you need

Comment: The operation have to be done only once at the installation of the program, once the refresh token is stored it won't be asked again, the batch will use the refresh token to get new access token again and again.